# Is there remarkable performance difference between this django app model construction?

Tags: django

**First case,**

```
app_1 - post_model_1

app_2 - post_model_2 (has Foreign Key Field to post_model_1)

app_3 - post_model_3 (has Foreign Key Field to post_model_1)
```

**Second case,**

```
app_1 - post_model_1, 
        post_model_2 (has Foreign Key Field to post_model_1), 
        post_model_3 (has Foreign Key Field to post_model_1),
```

If i do queryset like getting all related posts(whatever it is post_model_2, or post_model_3) to post_model_1 using ForeignKeyField,

**Is there performing difference between First case and Second case?**

**If it is, which is faster?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. They are the same. The same tables (models) you create in the first case, the same ones you create in the second case.

Note that Django apps do not determine database models (tables), but `Model`s do. So, in both cases you have the exact structure of models (three tables with `ForeignKey` relatioships). So, neither its "faster" or "better".

In the first case you would do:

```
from app_1 import post_model_1
from app_2 import post_model_2
from app_3 import post_model_3
```

while in the second one you would do:

```
from app_1 import post_model_1, post_model_2, post_model_3
```

The queryset will still remain the same.